# How to fit largest ellipsoid for 3d data points such that it covers all points?

Tags: matlab, ellipse, data-fitting

I search a lot for ellipsoid fit to 3d data and come up with some answer but I want some improvement in my method such that it covers all the data points. My code is here.

```
Y=data;  % data in non-principle coordinate 
X = data;
oldmu =mean(X);
X= bsxfun(@minus,X,oldmu); % mean-centered data
[pc val] = eig(X'*X  ); 

nC = X*pc;   % data in principle coordinate 
a2=(max(nC(:,1))-min(nC(:,1)))/2;  %range of data in X 
b2=(max(nC(:,2))-min(nC(:,2)))/2;  %range of data in Y
c2=(max(nC(:,3))-min(nC(:,3)))/2;  %range of data in Z
[x, y, z] = ellipsoid(0,0,0,a2,b2,c2,40); % fit ellipsoid in principle coordinate 

tt=[x(:) y(:) z(:)]*inv(pc);   %ellipsoid in non-principle coordinate
nx=reshape(tt(:,1),size(x,1),size(x,2));
ny=reshape(tt(:,2),size(x,1),size(x,2));
nz=reshape(tt(:,3),size(x,1),size(x,2));
% plot ellipsoid in non-principle coordinate 
hSurface=surf(nx+oldmu(1), ny+oldmu(2), nz+oldmu(3),    'FaceColor','r','EdgeColor','none','FaceAlpha',0.6);

hold on 
%plot data in non-principle coordinate 
plot3(Y(:,1),Y(:,2),Y(:,3),'k.-')
```

You can see the data here
[https://www.imsc.res.in/~aagrawal/data](https://www.imsc.res.in/%7Eaagrawal/data)
[image]

Comment: [possibly related](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/11935/algorithm-for-approximating-convex-bodies-by-a-convex-hull-of-ellipsoids)

and maybe [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/cluster/html/ellipsoidhull.html)

Comment: OK thats the [git](https://github.com/minillinim/ellipsoid/blob/master/ellipsoid.py) you probably want.

Comment: Thank you very much @mikuszefski . It's working awesome. Good

Comment: Good to hear. Cheers.